# combine bar and scatterplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data with a topic, if customers talk about it positive, negative or neutral and the topics impact and difference from the average.

```
data <- data.frame(topic = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), impact = runif(4, min = -2, max = 2), 
               difference = runif(4, min = -30, max = 30),n = round(runif(4, min = 1, max = 100)), 
               share_positive = c(0.04, 0.9, 0.3, 0.37), share_neutral = c(0.7, 0.06, 0.48, 0.4), 
               share_negative = c(0.26, 0.04, 0.22, 0.23))
```

I put it in a simple scatterplot:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = difference, y = impact, size = n, label = topic)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(size = 4, vjust = -1, colour = "black")
```

Then I added colour to distinct between positive and less positive topics:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = difference, y = impact, size = n, label = topic, colour = share_positive)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_continuous(low = "grey", high = "green", guide = FALSE) +
  geom_text(size = 4, vjust = -1, colour = "black")
```

Instead of the colouring, it would be nice to have bars which indicate the share of negative, neutral and positive feedback in this topic. My idea is something like this (example for b and d):

[image]

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea, how I can combine this and if it's even possible. Googeling doesn't help either. Can you help me?

Comment: I see one way but maybe it's not the easiest : calculate by hand the corner of your boxes and use `geom_rect`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, but it's sort of "hacky". We use the `difference` column and the `share_*` columns to manually define where `xmin` and `xmax` should be when we call `geom_rect`. To make sure we actually get a bar, we add a little fudge factor (0.1) to `ymax`

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw())

data %>%
    mutate(neg_left = difference - share_negative,
           neutral_right = difference + share_neutral,
           positive_right = neutral_right + share_positive) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(ymin = impact, ymax = impact + .1))+
    geom_text(aes(x = difference, y = impact, label = topic), vjust = 1)+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = neg_left, xmax = difference), fill = 'red', colour = 'black')+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = difference, xmax = neutral_right), fill = 'grey', colour = 'black')+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = neutral_right, xmax = positive_right), fill = 'green', colour = 'black')
```

[image]

#### Data (using `set.seed` for reproducibility)

```
set.seed(456)
data <- data.frame(topic = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), impact = runif(4, min = -2, max = 2), 
                   difference = runif(4, min = -30, max = 30),n = round(runif(4, min = 1, max = 100)), 
                   share_positive = c(0.04, 0.9, 0.3, 0.37), share_neutral = c(0.7, 0.06, 0.48, 0.4), 
                   share_negative = c(0.26, 0.04, 0.22, 0.23))
```

Comment: That is amazing! Thanks a lot @bouncyball